# Rails4 Friendly_id Unique Slug Formatting

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems, friendly-id

I am using friendly_id gem for slugging my models. Since the slug has to be unique when i enter the same data to check i get a long hashed appending in the slug.

```
Explore     explore 
Explore     explore-7a8411ac-5af5-41a3-ab08-d32387679f2b
```

Is there a way to tell friendly_id to give better formatted slugs like `explore-1` and `explore-2`

**Version:** `friendly_id 5.0.4`

Comment: Which version of friendly_id are you using?

Comment: @tirdadc friendly_id 5.0.4

Comment: Yeah, that looks like the new UUID feature that was introduced in 5.

Comment: @tirdadc any idea how i can get the format i want?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Agreed, it seems like pretty rough behavior.

If you look at code of `friendly_id/slugged.rb`, there are 2 functions handing conflicts resolution logic:

```
def resolve_friendly_id_conflict(candidates)
  candidates.first + friendly_id_config.sequence_separator + SecureRandom.uuid
end

# Sets the slug.
def set_slug(normalized_slug = nil)
  if should_generate_new_friendly_id?
    candidates = FriendlyId::Candidates.new(self, normalized_slug || send(friendly_id_config.base))
    slug = slug_generator.generate(candidates) || resolve_friendly_id_conflict(candidates)
    send "#{friendly_id_config.slug_column}=", slug
  end
end
```

So, the idea is just to monkey patch it. I see 2 options:

1. Just patch `resolve_friendly_id_conflict`, add your random suffix.
2. Change logic of both methods with intention of trying all candidates until `slug_generator.generate(candidates)` returns something not empty. If all candidates give `nil` then fallback to `resolve_friendly_id_conflict` method.
   Using this technique you can use slug candidates to append model's `id` when slug is not unique.

Ideally, it would be nice if gem's authors added a config option to handle unique slugs resolution (method symbol or proc taking generator and candidates as params) or just check if model responds to some method.

Besides, in some use cases unique slugs resolution in not needed at all. For example, if we just want to rely on `validates_uniqueness_of :slug` or uniqueness validation of candidates.

Comment: freak. i cant believe he thought its okay to have such a huge random string at the end. its just a slug.

Comment: thanks a lot :D can u tell me how i can do a monkey patching ?

Comment: just create an initializer like `friendly_id.rb` with something like this:

    module FriendlyId
      module Slugged
        def resolve_friendly_id_conflict(candidates)
          my_cool_unique_suffix = ...
          candidates.first + friendly_id_config.sequence_separator + my_cool_unique_suffix
        end
      end
    end

Comment: can you please pastebin.com the content. i am getting weird error

Comment: http://pastebin.com/rz2VHLFZ
You can just read more about monkey patching: http://www.runtime-era.com/2012/12/reopen-and-modify-ruby-classes-monkey.html
But don't abuse monkey patching. Once you need many changes it's better to fork a gem.

Comment: awesome. this works. thanks a lot. will wait and see if someone would post an answer to get the explore-1/explore-2 as well and then mark the answer.

Comment: Down voted as @tirdadc is a better solution for the question.

Answer (score 10):

So if anyone comes across this at some point, I have an update I would have preferred to put as a comment in tirdadc's comment, but I can't (not enough reputation).  So, here you go:

Tirdadc's answer is perfect, in theory, but unfortunately the id of an object isn't yet assigned at the point slug_candidates is called, so you need to do a little trickery.  Here's the full way to get a slug with the id of the object in there:

```
class YourModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  extend FriendlyId
  friendly_id :slug_candidates, use: :slugged
  after_create :remake_slug

  # Try building a slug based on the following fields in
  # increasing order of specificity.
  def slug_candidates
    [
      :name,
      [:name, :id],
    ]
  end

  def remake_slug
    self.update_attribute(:slug, nil)
    self.save!
  end

  #You don't necessarily need this bit, but I have it in there anyways
  def should_generate_new_friendly_id?
    new_record? || self.slug.nil?
  end
end
```

So you're basically setting the slug after the creation of the object and then after the object is done being created, you nil out the slug and perform a save, which will reassign the slug (now with the id intact).  Is saving an object in an after_create call dangerous?  Probably, but it seems to work for me.

Answer (score 7):

I would recommend using the `:scoped` module if you want to avoid UUIDs in your slugs when dealing with collisions. Here's the documentation along with an example:

http://norman.github.io/friendly_id/file.Guide.html#Unique_Slugs_by_Scope

Try using `:scope => :id` since each id will be unique anyway and see if that works for you.

UPDATE:

To get exactly what you want, you now have [`candidates`](http://norman.github.io/friendly_id/file.Guide.html#Candidates) for that purpose in version 5:

```
class YourModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  extend FriendlyId
  friendly_id :slug_candidates, use: :slugged

  # Try building a slug based on the following fields in
  # increasing order of specificity.
  def slug_candidates
    [
      :name,
      [:name, :id],
    ]
  end
end
```

Comment: undefined method `scope='   == Line == friendly_id :name, use: :slugged, :scope => :id

Comment: You need to have `use: :scoped`, not `use: :slugged`. Look at the example.

Comment: Did you try `slug_candidates`?

Comment: nope that may not work. as the ID is not created before the save its hard to get the unique small number after explore-$

Answer (score 3):

Today I came accross this issue and while other answer helped me get started, I wasn't satisfied because, like you, I wanted to have the slugs appear in sequence like `explore`, `explore-2`, `explore-3`.

So, here's how I fixed it:

```
class Thing < ActiveRecord::Base
  extend FriendlyId
  friendly_id :slug_candidates, use: :slugged

  validates :name, presence: true, uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }
  validates :slug, uniqueness: true

  def slug_candidates
    [:name, [:name, :id_for_slug]]
  end

  def id_for_slug
    generated_slug = normalize_friendly_id(name)
    things = self.class.where('slug REGEXP :pattern', pattern: "#{generated_slug}(-[0-9]+)?$")
    things = things.where.not(id: id) unless new_record?
    things.count + 1
  end

  def should_generate_new_friendly_id?
    name_changed? || super
  end
end
```

I used uniqueness validation for `:slug` just in case this model is being used in concurrent code.

Here you can see it working:

```
irb(main):001:0> Thing.create(name: 'New thing')
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
   (0.2ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "things" WHERE (slug REGEXP 'new-thing(-[0-9]+)?$')
  Thing Exists (0.1ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "things" WHERE ("things"."id" IS NOT NULL) AND "things"."slug" = ? LIMIT 1  [["slug", "new-thing"]]
  Thing Exists (0.1ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "things" WHERE LOWER("things"."name") = LOWER('New thing') LIMIT 1
  Thing Exists (0.1ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "things" WHERE "things"."slug" = 'new-thing' LIMIT 1
  SQL (0.4ms)  INSERT INTO "things" ("name", "slug") VALUES (?, ?)  [["name", "New thing"], ["slug", "new-thing"]]
   (115.7ms)  commit transaction
=> #<Thing id: 1, name: "New thing", slug: "new-thing">
irb(main):002:0> Thing.create(name: 'New thing')
   (0.2ms)  begin transaction
   (0.9ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "things" WHERE (slug REGEXP 'new-thing(-[0-9]+)?$')
  Thing Exists (0.1ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "things" WHERE ("things"."id" IS NOT NULL) AND "things"."slug" = ? LIMIT 1  [["slug", "new-thing"]]
  Thing Exists (0.1ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "things" WHERE ("things"."id" IS NOT NULL) AND "things"."slug" = ? LIMIT 1  [["slug", "new-thing-2"]]
  Thing Exists (0.1ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "things" WHERE LOWER("things"."name") = LOWER('New thing') LIMIT 1
  Thing Exists (0.1ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "things" WHERE "things"."slug" = 'new-thing-2' LIMIT 1
   (0.1ms)  rollback transaction
=> #<Thing id: nil, name: "New thing", slug: "new-thing-2">
irb(main):003:0> Thing.create(name: 'New-thing')
   (0.2ms)  begin transaction
   (0.5ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "things" WHERE (slug REGEXP 'new-thing(-[0-9]+)?$')
  Thing Exists (0.1ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "things" WHERE ("things"."id" IS NOT NULL) AND "things"."slug" = ? LIMIT 1  [["slug", "new-thing"]]
  Thing Exists (0.1ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "things" WHERE ("things"."id" IS NOT NULL) AND "things"."slug" = ? LIMIT 1  [["slug", "new-thing-2"]]
  Thing Exists (0.3ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "things" WHERE LOWER("things"."name") = LOWER('New-thing') LIMIT 1
  Thing Exists (0.3ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "things" WHERE "things"."slug" = 'new-thing-2' LIMIT 1
  SQL (0.4ms)  INSERT INTO "things" ("name", "slug") VALUES (?, ?)  [["name", "New-thing"], ["slug", "new-thing-2"]]
   (108.9ms)  commit transaction
=> #<Thing id: 2, name: "New-thing", slug: "new-thing-2">
irb(main):004:0> Thing.create(name: 'New!thing')
   (0.2ms)  begin transaction
   (0.6ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "things" WHERE (slug REGEXP 'new-thing(-[0-9]+)?$')
  Thing Exists (0.0ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "things" WHERE ("things"."id" IS NOT NULL) AND "things"."slug" = ? LIMIT 1  [["slug", "new-thing"]]
  Thing Exists (0.1ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "things" WHERE ("things"."id" IS NOT NULL) AND "things"."slug" = ? LIMIT 1  [["slug", "new-thing-3"]]
  Thing Exists (0.1ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "things" WHERE LOWER("things"."name") = LOWER('New!thing') LIMIT 1
  Thing Exists (0.1ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "things" WHERE "things"."slug" = 'new-thing-3' LIMIT 1
  SQL (0.1ms)  INSERT INTO "things" ("name", "slug") VALUES (?, ?)  [["name", "New!thing"], ["slug", "new-thing-3"]]
   (112.4ms)  commit transaction
=> #<Thing id: 3, name: "New!thing", slug: "new-thing-3">
irb(main):005:0>
```

Also, if you use sqlite3 adapter you'll need to install `sqlite3_ar_regexp` gem (it won't be very fast, because SQLite doesn't have REGEXP() and it evaluates Ruby code instead).

Comment: should be  the only acceptable answer, as if you use uuids instead of default ids (integer), `[:name, [:name, :id] ]` won't change much the result

Answer (score 2):

[Almir's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/920303/almir-saraj%C4%8Di%C4%87) solution helped me a lot but the **id_for_slug** method didn't work for me.

```
def id_for_slug
  generated_slug = normalize_friendly_id(name)
  things = self.class.where('slug REGEXP :pattern', pattern: "#generated_slug}(-[0-9]+)?$")
  things = things.where.not(id: id) unless new_record?
  things.count + 1
end
```

So I have modified that method like:

```
def id_for_slug
  Model.where('LOWER(table_name.name) = ?', name.downcase).count
end
```

and I think **should_generate_new_friendly_id?** method isn't mandatory.

I am attaching my model's picture here:
[slug_implementation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NDvAd.png)