# Use the ID inside slug when using FriendlyID

Tags: ruby-on-rails, friendly-id

Inside my model, I have the following:

```
friendly_id :id_and_title, use: [:slugged, :finders]

...

def id_and_title
    "#{self.id}-#{self.title}"[0,100]
end
```

However, when creating a new record, the `ID` isn't being used on the slug field.

What I'm currently doing is:

```
after_save :regenerate_slug

...

def regenerate_slug
    self.slug = nil
    self.save
end
```

and I'm wondering if there is any other way of doing this?

Comment: Your regenerate slug method can possibly cause infinite recurrence, you should change it.

Comment: What happens right now if you run this code?

Answer (score 0):

So the problem is that friendly_id does not have access to "id" until after the record is created. The issue here is the after_save causes infinite recurrence, like Michal said, since it calls save.

You should use an after_create instead. You only need to do this once. In all subsequent updates to the record the id should be available for friendly_id to pick up.

@user3062913 has the solution for it here:
[Rails4 Friendly_id Unique Slug Formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24306391/rails4-friendly-id-unique-slug-formating)

Comment: Btw your question helped me solve this when I had the same problem, so thanks!